# Set stdout for subprocess.Popen after contructor

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

Why can't set stdout, stdin and stderr after constructor subprocess.Popen("/bin/sh") ? I need this because as first i want find out pid of the process and then set stdout/stdin file with the same name as the pid number.

Like that :

```
self._process = Popen(["/bin/sh"])
self._stream_file = str(self._process.pid)
self._out_stream_write = open(self._stream_file,"ab")
self._out_stream_read = open(self._stream_file,"r")
self._process.stdin = PIPE
self._process.stdout = self._out_stream_write
self._process.stderr = self._out_stream_read
```

My IDE says

> "Instance of 'int' has no 'flush' member"

for this :

```
  self._process.stdin.write(data.encode("UTF-8"))
```

If i rewrite the self._process with this

```
self._process = Popen(["/bin/sh"],stdin=PIPE,stdout=self._out_stream_write,stderr=self._out_stream_write)
```

Everything is OK.

Comment: It's not possible to change the standard output of another process after it has started. This is an OS limitation, not Python.

Comment: You can redirect it to a temporary file, and rename it when done.